# Swift Local Network netServiceDidPublish not called

Tags: swift, bonjour

First question: I am using this [this method](https://gist.github.com/doozMen/0b5fc54c765bccb7c13792caa4eaa51c) to trigger LocalNetwork Permission dialog, but after dialog shows up, and users gives access, no delegate fires, however it enters to ready state.
Have you any idea why?

Second question: is there any possibility to detect if LocalNetwork permission was granted without trigger the dialog?

```
import Foundation
import Network

public class LocalNetworkAuthorization: NSObject {
    private var browser: NWBrowser?
    private var netService: NetService?
    private var completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    
    func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
        
            // Create parameters, and allow browsing over peer-to-peer link.
        let parameters = NWParameters()
        parameters.includePeerToPeer = true
        
            // Browse for a custom service type.
        let browser = NWBrowser(for: .bonjour(type: "_wobie._tcp", domain: nil), using: parameters)
        self.browser = browser
        browser.stateUpdateHandler = { newState in
            switch newState {
            case .failed(let error):
                print("::: ->> error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            case .ready:
                print("::: ->> ready")
            case .cancelled:
                print("::: ->> canceled")
                break
            case let .waiting(error):
                print("::: ->> Local network permission has been denied: \(error)")
                self.reset()
                self.completion?(false)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        self.netService = NetService(domain: "local.", type:"_lnp._tcp.", name: "LocalNetworkPrivacy", port: 1100)
        self.netService?.delegate = self
        
        self.browser?.start(queue: .main)
        self.netService?.publish()
    }
    
    
    private func reset() {
        self.browser?.cancel()
        self.browser = nil
        self.netService?.stop()
        self.netService = nil
    }
}

extension LocalNetworkAuthorization : NetServiceDelegate {
    public func netServiceDidPublish(_ sender: NetService) {
        self.reset()
        print("::: Local network permission has been granted")
        completion?(true)
    }
    
    public func netService(_ sender: NetService, didNotResolve errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print("::: error: \(errorDict)")
    }
    
    public func netService(_ sender: NetService, didAcceptConnectionWith inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) {
        print("")
    }
    
    public func netServiceWillResolve(_ sender: NetService) {
        print("")
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. All the code should be in the question as code not a link to a repo, links break over time and are not searchable in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't added "_lnp._tcp." to Bonjour services.